# Titles are not showing in the navigation bar iphone app

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, title

Titles are not showing after the home screen. I have put `UITabBarController` after the first screen. First screen hasn't got a `UITabBarController`. I am not sure the way I have implemented the tab.

I have set titles in every view controller by `self.title = @"title"`. Titles are showing in tab items properly.

AppDelegate.m:

```
 UIViewController *loginView= [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

UINavigationController *loginViewNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView ];

self.navigationController = loginViewNavController;

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

LoginViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)navigateMainMenu:(id)sender{

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

MyAccountsViewController *vc1 = [[MyAccountsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyAccountsViewController" bundle:nil];
DepositsViewController *vc2 = [[DepositsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DepositsViewController" bundle:nil];
MoreViewController *vc3 = [[MoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreViewController" bundle:nil];
PayTransViewController *vc4 = [[PayTransViewController alloc]init];

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc4, vc2, vc3, nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];

[mainMenuViewController release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set self.title = @"Title". This title will set in navController title. But In your TabBarController, every items are ViewController. Not an navigationController.

Issue: What you release in this line 
`[mainMenuViewController release];`

Answer (score 2):

mostly display title with bellow trickes :-

```
1. Self.title=@"Your Titile";

2. self.navigationItem.title=@"your Title";

3. when you using UItabBarController you can set Particular Viewcontroller as par your code Title like:- 

  vc1.title=@"your Title";
  vc2.title=@"your Title";
  vc3.title=@"your Title";
  vc4.title=@"your Title";
```

Comment: `1` doesn't work for me. But `2` works. Could you tell me why? thx.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not you use tabbarcontroller inside a navigationcontroller. If you are using tabbarcontroller it should be the rootViewcontroller.